# How to add User defined data type such as date/time in structure in cpp?

Tags: datetime, user-defined-types

I have made a Date class. It takes input and display output correctly. But how can I use this class in structures. Because the data is actually saved in variables y,m,d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since how is obvious, just put the name in the struct, I'm guessing you are confused about how to call the constructor to initialize the thing.  Since a class really is a struct, a struct initializer will call the constructor for the embedded class.   Here's an example.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Date_Time
{
public:
  int Date;
  int Time;

  Date_Time(const int date, const int time)
  {
    Date = date;
    Time = time;
  };
};

int main() {
  struct state {
    Date_Time dt;
  } st = {{5, 6}};
  cout << "Date: " << st.dt.Date << endl;
  cout << "Time: " << st.dt.Time << endl;
}
```

I compiled with:

```
g++ -std=c++0x foo.cpp
```

An alternative is to put a pointer to the class in the struct and initialize it with `new`.